# Find and delete all symlinks in home folder, having trouble making it work

Tags: shell, zsh

I have the following:

```
read -p 'Delete old symlinks? y/n: ' prompt

if [ $prompt == [yY] ]
then    
    current_dir=$(pwd)
    script_dir=$(dirname $0)

    if [ $script_dir = '.' ]
    then
        script_dir="$current_dir"
    fi

    for sym in {find $PATH -type l -xtype d -lname "~"}
    do
        rm $sym
        echo "Removed: $sym"
    done
fi
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

- If prompt equals y (yes)
  Then:
  Find all the symlinks in `~` (home directory) and do a for loop on them which would delete them and output which one it deleted.

Although right now it doesn't do the deleting part, the rest works fine. I didn't include the part that works, it's just a bunch of `ln -s`.

I am in Mac OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.2), using Zsh as shell, this goes in a `.sh` file.

The problem I am having is that nothing happens, and so it just says:

```
ln: /Users/eduan/.vim/vim: File exists
ln: /Users/eduan/.vimrc: File exists
ln: /Users/eduan/.gvimrc: File exists
Done...
```

etc.

Many thanks for any help you can provide!

**EDIT:**
I now have the following:

```
read -p 'Delete old symlinks? y/n: ' prompt

if [ $prompt == [yY] ]
then    
   find ~ -type l | while read line
   do
      rm -v "$line"
   done
fi
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem, turns out it was the if conditional that wasn't working. Thanks for your help anyway guys! :)

Comment: This might be one of those Question/Answer-pairs where one could question if the answer marked as Answer (OP's own answer), is the proper Answer. As stated in the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is the OP who can decide what solution fits his request the best. Also, his solution are given as an edit of the question. The effort of those trying to assist are left uncredited though, and the information in the Answer are of no value. Questions in the question section, answers in the answer section.

Answer (score 16):

```
find /path -type l | xargs rm
```

The first part lists the symlinks. `Xargs` says for each of the returned values issue an `rm`

Comment: I think it's `find` instead of `Find`. I will try it now. :)

Comment: Same problem though... It keeps telling me that the symlinks already exist, that's the error I keep coming to. :/

Comment: I've been trying other simpler methods and stuff and I am not able to solve it. :/

Comment: you could also `find /path -type l -delete`, for completeness sake.

Comment: you should add `-0` to `xargs` to handle spaces

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
find ~ -type l | while read line
do
   rm -v "$line"
done
```

Comment: I tried it, replacing all of the for loop, but it didn't work, same problem, doesn't do anything.

Comment: What exactly does `rm --verbose "$line"` output?

Comment: I've been trying other simpler methods and stuff and I am not able to solve it. :/