# Packer cannot upload modules

Tags: virtualbox, puppet, packer

Using 0.5.2 Packer. Got the following packer provisioner in conf file.

```
{
    "type": "puppet-masterless",
    "manifest_file": "site.pp",
    "module_paths": ["puppet_modules"],
    "execute_command": "{{.FacterVars}}{{if .Sudo}} sudo -E {{end}}/opt/ruby/bin/puppet apply --verbose --modulepath='{{.ModulePath}}' {{if ne .HieraConfigPath \"\"}}--hiera_config='{{.HieraConfigPath}}' {{end}} {{if ne .ManifestDir \"\"}}--manifestdir='{{.ManifestDir}}' {{end}} --detailed-exitcodes {{.ManifestFile}}"
},
```

When running, it fails uploading the puppet modules.

```
virtualbox-iso: Provisioning with Puppet...
virtualbox-iso: Creating Puppet staging directory...
virtualbox-iso: Uploading local modules from: puppet_modules
virtualbox-iso: Unregistering and deleting virtual machine...
virtualbox-iso: Error deleting virtual machine: VBoxManage error:
virtualbox-iso: Deleting output directory...
Build 'virtualbox-iso' errored: Error uploading modules: lstat /Users: no such file or directory
```

The packer validate works fine. It seems packer is not using the staging directory of the manifest for the modules. This "/User" bothers me, looks like OSX dir :/

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Found some clue with https://github.com/mitchellh/packer/issues/863.

I add a symlink in one of the puppet modules.

```
ls -lR . | grep ^l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 foo foo   37 févr.  3 14:30 nodejs -> /Users/william/projects/puppet-nodejs
```

Just add to remove it and everything went fine (see [Find and delete all symlinks in home folder, having trouble making it work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484825/find-and-delete-all-symlinks-in-home-folder-having-trouble-making-it-work))

```
find /path -type l | xargs rm
```